# WinRT - Listview custom selection

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to achieve custom selection of selected item in listview. In default, selected item has border around it. I wanted to add CornerRadius to it but couldn't. So I decided to add my own border in ItemTemplate and make it visible for the currently selected item only.

Here's my ItemTemplate for Listview:

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
             <Border Height="73"
                     Width="73">
                 <Image Stretch="UniformToFill"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Source="{Binding ImgPath}">
                 </Image>
             </Border>
             <Border x:Name="CornerRadiusBorder"
                     Height="78"
                     Width="77"
                     BorderBrush="Blue"
                     BorderThickness="3"
                     CornerRadius="3">
             </Border>
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I want to make CornerRadiusBorder visible only for selected item.

Comment: I don't know how well this will work in WinRT, but check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146269/change-wpf-datatemplate-for-listbox-item-if-selected) out. The idea is to apply your rounded border as an  `ItemContainerStyle`, instead of within the `ItemTemplate`.

Comment: What you need has already answered here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150683/styling-selecteditem-in-listview-in-metro-app-xaml

Comment: @BurakKaanKöse I've already implemented it. That solution only allows selection thickness and color change.

Comment: Border element has CornerRadius property inside that template , you can easily edit that though.

Comment: @MikeEason didn't work for WinRT. Style.Triggers not available.

Comment: @BurakKaanKöse Please paste the code. I've already played with template but no use.